# how to cut first 3 folders from this echo "/home/test/var/opt" ? i need the result "/home/test/var"

Tags: directory, filenames, cut

How to cut first 3 folders from a string?

For example:

```
echo "/home/source/Oracle/test" |cut -d'/' -f4
```

gives only one folder name, but I need up to the 3rd folder, like below:

```
echo "/home/test/var/opt" | ... command here ...
```

should return `/home/test/var`

Answer (score 1):

Use `cut -d "/" -f1-4`

```
ebvjr@Maintenance:~$ echo /home/test/var/opt | cut -d "/" -f1-4
/home/test/var
```

Comment: Great. One more correct answer. This worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

`cut` is fine as @ebvjr says, just remember that you need 4 fields because the first is empty.

If you `grep` then the code is longer but perhaps more intuitive (`{3}` = the 3rd sub-folder).

```
grep -Po "(/[^/]+){3}" <<<"/home/test/var/opt"
/home/test/var
```

Comment: Great. Thanks for your time and helping here. it working

Answer (score 0):

Usually, pathnames are modified through the two utilities `basename` and `dirname`, or through parameter substitutions, rather than by line-based text editing utilities.

This is because, technically, pathnames may contain newlines, which would make it difficult to work on the reliably with line-based tools such as `cut` (or `sed` or `awk` etc.)

The example that you have is to get the pathname of the parent directory of `/home/test/var/opt`.  This is best done with

```
dirname /home/test/var/opt
```

This would return `/home/test/var`.  This would work even if the given pathname had a `/` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I have done by below awk method

command

```
echo "/home/test/var/opt"| awk -F "/" 'OFS="/"{print $1,$2,$3,$4}'
```

output

```
/home/test/var
```